# Expectation for Group Testing

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

The question involves considering the following group testing scheme:

Suppose the original sample of size N is divided into two groups, and each of the subgroups is tested as a whole. If either subgroup tests positive, it is divided in two, and the procedure is repeated. If any of the groups thus obtained tests positive, test every member of that group.

Find the expected total number of tests performed.

---

If we suppose that each individual is disease-free with probability, p, then it is clear that for each subgroup of size k, it will test positive with probability $(1-p^k)$ i.e. at least one individual is positive in the group.

Taking $X_k$ to denote the no. of tests run on a given subgroup of size $k$, then

$$
P(X_k = 1) = p^k \quad \text{i.e. Test subgroup once, produce a -ve test}
$$

and

$$
P(X_k = k+1) = 1-p^k \quad \text{i.e. Test subgroup $k+1$ times.}
$$

Given that the size of the subgroups are halved depending on whether it contains an infected individual (i.e. you can have one subgroup testing positive or both subgroups testing positive), I am having some difficulty forming the expectation as the total number of subgroups that will be formed is also varying.

Appreciate if anyone has guiding ideas on how to approach this problem!

Comment: Is it counting one test as a test on a group or a test on an individual person?

Comment: Hi Ian, my interpretation of the phrasing from the question (I copied exactly), is that you first perform +1 test on the whole group. If it is a +ve test, then you perform a test on all the individuals in the group, before you split the group into 2 again.

Comment: Have you seen any problems where you compute an expected value recursively, for example the expected number of draws without replacement from an urn before you get a ball of a specified color?

Comment: I thought of the negative hypergeometric distribution, but I have never worked its expectation before

Comment: The point of my suggestion is that you don't need to actually assemble the distribution of the number of tests to get its expected value. If $T_n$ is the expected total number of tests done on a group of size $n$, then you can use the total expectation formula (conditioning on whether the group-level test is positive or not) to get something of the form $E[T_n]=p \cdot (\dots) + (1-p) \cdot (\dots)$. Here one of those ellipses involves $E[T_m]$ again but for a smaller $m$ (in this case $n/2$).